# VBA: Copy paste range across workbooks object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I can't copy a range across workbooks. There are similar posts ([VBA copy-paste offset to another workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676014/vba-copy-paste-offset-to-another-workbook)) related to this but none seem to help with the application-defined or object-defined error.

I have tried this

```
       Set wbSource = Workbooks("Source.xlsx")
       Set wbTarget = Workbooks("Target.xlsx")
       Set wbSource_WS = wbSource.Worksheets("Source")
       Set wbSTarget_WS = wbTarget.Worksheets("Target")

       wbSource_WS.Activate
       wbSource_WS.Range(Cells(Row_SourceStart, Col_Source), Cells(Row_SourceEnd, Col_Source)).Copy
       wbTarget_WS.Activate
       wbSTarget_WS.Range(Cells(Row_TargetStart, Col_TargetStart), Cells(Row_TargetStart, Col_TargetEnd)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

And this too:

```
       wbSource_WS.Range(Cells(Row_SourceStart, Col_Source), Cells(Row_SourceEnd, Col_Source)).Copy Destination:= _
       wbSTarget_WS.Range(Cells(Row_TargetStart, Col_TargetStart), Cells(Row_TargetStart, Col_TargetEnd)).PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True)
```

Comment: try using this...
`wbSTarget_WS.Range(Cells(Row_TargetStart, Col_TargetStart)).PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True)`

Comment: There can be an error of size mismatch of source and target ranges...

Comment: I debugged my code. The source and target ranges are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fully declare the objects in the ranges:

```
 wbSource_WS.Activate
 wbSource_WS.Range(Cells(Row_SourceStart, Col_Source), Cells(Row_SourceEnd, Col_Source)).Copy
```

Should look like:

```
 wbSource_WS.Activate
 wbSource_WS.Range(wbSource_WS.Cells(Row_SourceStart, Col_Source), wbSource_WS.Cells(Row_SourceEnd, Col_Source)).Copy
```

Each .cells in the .range needs to be tied to: wbSource_WS

Would be a little simpler/cleaner to just use a With Statement:

```
With wbSource_WS
    .Range( .Cells(Row_SourceStart, Col_Source), .Cells(Row_SourceEnd, Col_Source)).Copy
End With
```

Comment: You would do this for all instances; just gave the first instance as an example.

Comment: This works in clearing the "object-defined error" but now a new error "unable to get the pastespecial property of the range class" appears which I am trying to fix now

Comment: @diana Have you tried pasting to the range without .pastespecial to see if it works?  With a fully-defined range, you might want to just choose the upper-left cell of the desired range to paste.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your code.

```
Set wbSource = Workbooks("Source.xlsx")
   Set wbTarget = Workbooks("Target.xlsx")
   Set wbSource_WS = wbSource.Worksheets("Source")
   Set wbSTarget_WS = wbTarget.Worksheets("Target")

   wbSource_WS.Activate
   wbSource_WS.Range(Cells(Row_SourceStart, Col_Source), Cells(Row_SourceEnd, Col_Source)).Copy
   **wbSTarget_WS.Activate**
   wbSTarget_WS.Range(Cells(Row_TargetStart, Col_TargetStart), Cells(Row_TargetStart, Col_TargetEnd)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I ran it with this small change and it produced no errors.

I would recommend you use Option Explicit. It would prevent this error from happening again. Excel will point out that there's an undeclared variable even before letting you run the VBA program.